# integrate a fraction of trig functions

Tags: calculus

I need to compute $$\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+\sin(x)}dx$$

and I believe that $u$-substitution is the correct approach but not sure what to set $u$ to or if I should use trig identities to change the function first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I would note that

$$\cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x = (1 - \sin x) (1 + \sin x)$$
$$\implies \frac{\cos^2 x}{1 + \sin x} = 1 - \sin x$$

which can be integrated easily

Answer (score 1):

Another way to reach the correct solution of @J. Marx-Kuo, is to note that the denominator, $1+\sin{x}$ can always be simplified by multiplying it by $1-\sin{x}$, to yield $\cos^2{x}$

Of course, you need to multiply the numerator by the same factor, $1-\sin{x}$.  When the dust settles, there remains the same integrand as in other solutions...